# Truncate a string with JQuery and set back to the element

Tags: jquery, string

I have a function to truncate a string and set the new string back to the element. I can get as far as truncating the string but can't set the truncated string back to the element.

**HTML**:

```
<p class="myString"> I am a very long string.</p>
```

**SCRIPT**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var newTitle = $('.myString').text().substr(0, 4);
  var titleElement = $('.myString');
  titleElement.text() = newTitle;
});
```

How do I set the text back to the same element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var newTitle = $('.myString').text().substr(0, 4);
        var titleElement = $('.myString');
        titleElement.text(newTitle);   //pass the newTitle to text function.
});
```